# How to Change Position of RangeSlider in R Plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to somehow move the range slider toggle down further below the plot [image of plot + range slider here, had to only show a portion of the image due to confidentiality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q561H.png). Is it possible to do this? I will paste my code for the plot below:

```
    output$p <- renderPlotly({
    plot1 <- plot_ly(x = x(), y = y(), name = as.character(input$select), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers+lines', color = I("#696969")) %>% 
        add_lines(y = meaan(), name = paste("Mean =", meaan()[1]), color = I("black")) %>%
        add_lines(y = ucl(), name = paste("UCL =", ucl()[1]), color = I("green")) %>%
        add_lines(y = lcl(), name = paste("LCL =", lcl()[1]), color = I("green")) %>%
       add_lines(y = usl(), name = paste("USL =", usl()[1]), color = I("red")) %>%
       add_lines(y = lsl(), name = paste("LSL =", lsl()[1]), color = I("red")) %>%
        add_trace(x=r5x(),y=r5y(),mode='markers', color = I("blue"), name = paste("R 5  =", length(r5())))%>%
        add_trace(x=r4x(),y=r4y(),mode='markers', color = I("yellow"), name = paste("R 4 =", length(r4()))) %>%
        add_trace(x=r1x(),y=r1y(),mode='markers', color = I("red"), name = paste("R 1 =", length(r1()))) %>%
        layout(
            title = paste("Test", input$select),
            yaxis = list(  showline = TRUE,
                           mirror = "ticks",
                           linecolor = toRGB("grey"),
                           linewidth = 1.85
            ),
            xaxis = list(  showline = TRUE,
                           mirror = "ticks",
                           linecolor = toRGB("grey"),
                           linewidth = 1.85,
                rangeselector = list(
                    buttons = list(
                        list(
                            count = 3,
                            label = "3 mo",
                            step = "month",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 6,
                            label = "6 mo",
                            step = "month",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 1,
                            label = "1 yr",
                            step = "year",
                            stepmode = "backward"),
                        list(
                            count = 1,
                            label = "YTD",
                            step = "year",
                            stepmode = "todate"),
                        list(step = "all"))),
    
    rangeslider = list(type = "date", thickness=0.2)))
                
})
```